# React/NextJS - Audio player

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I need to stream an audio using the *mp3 endpoint url*.

I am new to audio streaming, so I could really use some help. Thanks in advance.

This is what I have tried:

```
const SongRow = ({ track }) => {
    const player = useRef();
    const playSong = () => {
        player.src = track.preview_url;
        player.play();
    }
    return (
        <div className="songRow" onClick={() => playSong()}>
            <audio ref={player} />
            <div className="songRow__info">
                <h1>{track.name}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};
```

> **Error** : TypeError: Cannot add property src, object is not extensible

I am not sure how I am supposed to proceed with this. Also couldn't find any relevant docs related to this and functional components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the `current` property on the ref.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs):

> a reference to the node becomes accessible at the `current` attribute of the ref.

So it would be `player.current.src`.